# text filter functions on Data google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

i need help please about my google sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hbzZ7becv_CAXXWFslEwpkDUnCsDFIz_axWhE5dWUe4/edit?usp=sharing

This my google sheets
I am looking for a formula to present my information from column A to column H and I
That is all the text in column A:1 I have the "Purchase order number" is shown on column H:1 Number 16826

An example can be seen in sheet Example

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clear all content in column H and I. Then in cell H1 enter

```
=ArrayFormula({"purchase_order FINAL"; regexextract(A2:A, "order number:\n\n(\d+)\n")})
```

and in I1

```
=ArrayFormula({"tracking_numbers FINAL"; regexextract(A2:A, "Tracking number:\n\n(\d+)\n")})
```

and see if that works ?

Comment: Can you explain to me the formula please?

Comment: The regex extracts the digits (\d+) after the two new line characters (\n\n) found after the words 'order number' and 'tracking number'.